# Dynamically override page.php or single.php with custom templates using function

Tags: plugin-development, page-template

I want to add new custom templates in my plugin (custom-page.php, custom-single.php). When activated, I want to dynamically use my plugin's custom templates to override the templates (page.php, single.php) of the theme.

Is there a function that can do this?

Comment: hi! I found your question very useful, thank you. 
I have a question: how can you integrate your new templates from your plugin into any Wordpress theme? I mean, any WP theme is different...how can you preserve the aspect of the current theme? thankyou in advance! M.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can do that is by adding a filter to the hook [`{$type}_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/).

Sample code:

```
function my_plugin_custom_template( $template, $type ) {
    switch ( $type ) {
        case 'page':
            $template = '/path/to/custom-page-template';
            break;

        case 'single':
            $template = '/path/to/custom-single-template';
            break;
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'page_template', 'my_plugin_custom_template', 10, 2 );   // Filter for page.php
add_filter( 'single_template', 'my_plugin_custom_template', 10, 2 ); // Filter for single.php
```

Or you can also add a filter to the hook [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/).

Sample code:

```
function my_plugin_custom_template2( $template ) {
    if ( is_page() ) {
        $template = '/path/to/custom-page-template';
    }
    elseif ( is_single() ) {
        $template = '/path/to/custom-single-template';
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_plugin_custom_template2' );
```

It's up to you to decide which hook to filter; however, the `template_include` filter is called *after* the `{$type}_template` hook. And if you look at the `my_plugin_custom_template()` code, you basically don't need to check whether the current page (i.e. queried object) is a Page, Post, etc.

Hope that helps.